# A believing ‘B to be not B’, and by implication someone else (not void) v. A believing ‘B to be C, mistakenly believing that C exists’ (void)

Tags: contract-law, england-and-wales

I can't grasp the distinction boldened in the quote below. How does

> A believing ‘B to be not B’, and by implication someone else

differ from

> A believing ‘B to be C, mistakenly believing that C exists’

? Mindy Chen-Wishart. [*Contract Law* (2018 6 edn)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Contract-Law-Mindy-Chen-Wishart/dp/0198806353/ref=dp_ob_title_bk). p 262.

> ### 6.2.5 Non-existence of the identity assumed
>
> According to this rule, A’s mistake as to B’s identity will only void their contract if
>   A mistook B for another existing and identifiable party, C. If A merely believes that
>   B is C who is non-existent or unidentifiable, the contract is only voidable. In *King’s
>   Norton Metal Co Ltd v Edridge, Merrett & Co Ltd* (1897), K sent goods in response to an
>   order from the fictitious ‘Hallam & Co’, written on headed stationery with a picture
>   of a large factory and a list of overseas depots. The fraudster then sold the goods
>   to E. Although the contract was in writing, the contract was only voidable for fraud
>   because K intended to contract with the writer of the letter, being mistaken only as to
>   his attributes; namely, solvency and respectability. The contract was not void for K’s
>   mistake that it was contracting with ‘Hallam & Co’ because ‘Hallam & Co’ was nonexistent.
>   ‘If it could have been shown that there was a separate entity called Hallam &
>   Co . . . then the case might have come within the decision in *Cundy v Lindsay*.’
>         It is difficult to see why A and D’s rights should depend on whether A mistook B for
>   another real entity or not. Furthermore, why was it not enough in King’s Norton that K
>   believed that ‘Hallam & Co’ existed, when it did not?
>   This supposed rule is subject to two exceptions, which require impossible distinctions
>   to be drawn:
>
> (i) A contract may be voided if A makes the additional mistake that **C exists, even
>   if C does not exist. But is there a meaningful difference between A believing ‘B to be
>   not B’, and by implication someone else (contract not void); and A believing ‘B to be
>   C, mistakenly believing that C exists’ (contract is void)?** After all, in *Lake v Simmons*

p 263.

> (1927), the mistress of a wealthy customer, a widower, purchased some items from L,
>   and then persuaded L to let her take away valuable pearl necklaces for her ‘husband’s
>   approval’. L’s loss was only insured if no valid contract was made with the mistress.
>   The court so found, although she was posing as a non-existent wife.
>
> (ii) A contract is void when A believes that B who pretends to be C is not B (whether
>   C exists or not), as long as there is an implied term that B is not B (*Said v Butt* (1920)),
>   as where:
>
> • an offer is made only to persons fitting particular descriptions which excludes
>   B (eg ‘current students of a particular university’, or being ‘over 18 years’ to
>   buy alcohol); or
>   • B may know from previous dealings that A is unwilling to contract with
>   them (eg B is barred from a pub or a soccer match).
>
> If the rationale is merely that B cannot accept an offer known not to be meant for
>   her, then why did this not apply in *King’s Norton Metal* when the fraudster must have
>   known that K had no intention of contracting with him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does A believing ‘B to be not B’, and by implication someone else differ from A believing ‘B to be C, mistakenly believing that C exists’?

The difference stems from A's *manifest reluctance* to contract specifically with B or with any sets of entitites in which B belongs. The author entangles herself as usual in that textbook, but the key point is "*the rationale [...] that B cannot accept an offer known not to be meant for her*". This is a consequence of the tenet that contracts are entered *knowingly and willfully*.

A's manifest reluctance to contract with B implies that there cannot be cognizable offers from A to B. There being no offer, B's acceptance thereof is a *non sequitur*. Consequently, the requisite conditions for the formation of a contract are not met.